# Dataflow Python SDK Avro Source/Sync

Tags: python, avro, google-cloud-dataflow

I am looking to ingest and write Avro files in GCS with the Python SDK. Is this currently possible with Avro leveraging the Python SDK? If so how would I do this? I see TODO comments in the source regarding this so I am not too optimistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: the Python SDK does not yet support this, but it will soon.

Comment: Any clue as to how soon? I keep checking the beam github to see if it has been added. We are currently using the Java SDK because of this.

Comment: We hope to add an Avro sink within next two months. Python SDK already has an Avro source: https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/python-sdk/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/avroio.py

Comment: Is it available now?

Answer (score 6):

As of version 2.6.0 of the Apache Beam/Dataflow Python SDK, it is indeed possible to read (and write to) avro files in GCS.

Even better, the Python SDK for Beam now supports `fastavro` reads and writes which can be upto 10x faster than regular avro IO.

Sample code:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromAvro
from apache_beam.io import WriteToAvro
import avro.schema


RUNNER = 'DataflowRunner'
GCP_PROJECT_ID = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'
BUCKET_NAME = 'YOUR_BUCKET_HERE'
STAGING_LOCATION = 'gs://{}/staging'.format(BUCKET_NAME)
TEMP_LOCATION = 'gs://{}/temp'.format(BUCKET_NAME)
GCS_INPUT = "gs://{}/input-*.avro".format(BUCKET_NAME)
GCS_OUTPUT = "gs://{}/".format(BUCKET_NAME)
JOB_NAME = 'conversion-test'

SCHEMA_PATH="YOUR_AVRO_SCHEMA.avsc"
AVRO_SCHEMA = avro.schema.parse(open(SCHEMA_PATH).read())

OPTIONS = {
    'runner': RUNNER,
    'job_name': JOB_NAME,
    'staging_location': STAGING_LOCATION,
    'temp_location': TEMP_LOCATION,
    'project': GCP_PROJECT_ID,
    'max_num_workers': 2,
    'save_main_session': True,
}

PIPELINE = beam.Pipeline(options=beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **OPTIONS))


def main():
    # note: have to force `use_fastavro` to enable `fastavro`:
    results = PIPELINE | ReadFromAvro(file_pattern=GCS_INPUT, use_fastavro=True)
    results | WriteToAvro(file_path_prefix=GCS_OUTPUT, schema=AVRO_SCHEMA, use_fastavro=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY'
    main()
```