# Use fastavro when reading from BigQuery using Apache Beam/Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My project is running Python 2.7 (yes, I know...) with Apache Beam 2.19 on Google Dataflow. We're connecting to BigQuery in the same way that's specified in the Apache Beam tutorial:

```
p | 'Get data from BigQuery' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
    query=get_query(limit),
    use_standard_sql=True)))
```

However, the read-step of this Pipeline is incredibly slow - most likely due to the reading of .avro-files. It doesn't seem like `fastavro` is actually being used, though. AFAIK, you need to set the `use_fastavro` flag explicitly when running on Python <3.7. Is that even possible with this setup? Or will I need to, manually, export to GCS first?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of beam are you running? At beam version 2.6+, you can enable use_fastavro as shown here:

[Dataflow Python SDK Avro Source/Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799065/dataflow-python-sdk-avro-source-sync)

It looks like for more recent beam SDKs fastavro defaults to true if you are using python 3+, but you can still manually enable it
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4743e131edadad42555e605be803e26cb37b7ce6/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/avroio.py#L81

I don't see any warnings about not settings this for prior python versions, so you may want to give this a try and see if this works.

Comment: I'm using Beam 2.19. I've looked at the links you provided, but if Im not mistaken those assume that I'm reading Avro files directly? In our pipeline I'm using BigQuerySource with io.Read, so I don't think the use_fastavro is exposed.

Comment: Correct, that feature is only provided for TextIO reading avro files directly

Comment: I see. Do you know if fastavro is used by default for Python 3 when reading using BigQuerySource? Or is it just for TextIO there as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't beleive there is a helper to read Avro rows from BigQuery yet. There is however a writer, which uses fast avro. You could give it a try to write a similar AvroRowReader implementation. Or if you store your data in BigQuery as bytes. Then you could read it out and parse it manually in a downstream ParDo. You could manually invoke fastavro for this.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9a3ba93d4313de9280fa5edf708e5aeb4efbb70e/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py#L1239